# How to create a new column in Polars based on the most recent occurrence of a specific value in another column (before the next occurrence)?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have a`polars` `DataFrame` with three columns: `Patient_id`, `Event` and `Date`. I want to create a new column, `latest_admission`, that records the most recent`Event == "Admission"` (by `Date`). The "latest" value should be recorded in each row until the next `"Admission"`. How can I achieve this using Polars?

Here's an example of the DataFrame:

```
import polars as pl

df1 = (pl.DataFrame
       ._from_dict({
        'Patient_id': [1, 1, 1, 1,1,2,2,2],     
        'Event': ["Admission", "Discharge", "Admission", 
                  "Other", "Discharge", "Admission", "Discharge", "Admission"],
        'Date': ["2020/01/01","2020/01/02","2021/04/18","2021/04/19","2021/04/20",
                 "2020/12/01","2020/12/02","2022/08/17"]})
       .with_columns(
           pl.col(["Date"]).str.strptime(pl.Date, format="%Y/%m/%d")))
```

And this is the expected output:

```
shape: (8, 4)
┌────────────┬───────────┬────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ Patient_id ┆ Event     ┆ Date       ┆ latest_admission │
│ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---              │
│ i64        ┆ str       ┆ date       ┆ date             │
╞════════════╪═══════════╪════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ 1          ┆ Admission ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 2020-01-01       │
│ 1          ┆ Discharge ┆ 2020-01-02 ┆ 2020-01-01       │
│ 1          ┆ Admission ┆ 2021-04-18 ┆ 2021-04-18       │
│ 1          ┆ Other     ┆ 2021-04-19 ┆ 2021-04-18       │
│ 1          ┆ Discharge ┆ 2021-04-20 ┆ 2021-04-18       │
│ 2          ┆ Admission ┆ 2020-12-01 ┆ 2020-12-01       │
│ 2          ┆ Discharge ┆ 2020-12-02 ┆ 2020-12-01       │
│ 2          ┆ Admission ┆ 2022-08-17 ┆ 2022-08-17       │
└────────────┴───────────┴────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
df1.filter(pl.col('Event')=='Admission')
```

Then you have the admission dates. Now you want to join that to the original.

```
df1.join_asof(
    df1.filter(pl.col('Event')=='Admission'),
  on='Date', by='Patient_id')
```

Of course the output of that isn't quite what we want as it gives us the Event column again and only keeps the df1 date. We need to copy the Date column so it can still join from it but since we want to keep the admission date we need that copy. We also want to exclude the Event column since we know the Event is Admission.

To clean this up we want to make the Admission date `df` to look like this:

```
(df1 
.filter(pl.col('Event')=='Admission')
.select(
    'Patient_id',
    'Date',
    latest_admission=pl.col('Date')
    )
)
```

then we can put that back inside the join

```
df1.join_asof(
    df1 
        .filter(pl.col('Event')=='Admission')
        .select(
            'Patient_id',
            'Date',
            latest_admission=pl.col('Date')
            ),
on='Date', by='Patient_id')

shape: (8, 4)
┌────────────┬───────────┬────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ Patient_id ┆ Event     ┆ Date       ┆ latest_admission │
│ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---              │
│ i64        ┆ str       ┆ date       ┆ date             │
╞════════════╪═══════════╪════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ 1          ┆ Admission ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 2020-01-01       │
│ 1          ┆ Discharge ┆ 2020-01-02 ┆ 2020-01-01       │
│ 1          ┆ Admission ┆ 2021-04-18 ┆ 2021-04-18       │
│ 1          ┆ Other     ┆ 2021-04-19 ┆ 2021-04-18       │
│ 1          ┆ Discharge ┆ 2021-04-20 ┆ 2021-04-18       │
│ 2          ┆ Admission ┆ 2020-12-01 ┆ 2020-12-01       │
│ 2          ┆ Discharge ┆ 2020-12-02 ┆ 2020-12-01       │
│ 2          ┆ Admission ┆ 2022-08-17 ┆ 2022-08-17       │
└────────────┴───────────┴────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Setting `strategy='backward'` isn't necessary because that is the default but it won't hurt anything to include it.

Comment: This generates a new column called `Event_right` with all values being `Admission`.  Which is not the same. But I think you are in the right track with the `join_asof` function!

Comment: It worked with `df1.join_asof(
    df1.filter(pl.col('Event')=='Admission')
        .with_columns(pl.col("Date").alias("latest_admission")), on='Date', by='Patient_id', strategy = "backward")`. If you want you can edit your answer for this(?).

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a mobile answer. I'll edit a final in the next time I'm at a computer.